# AWS command line on Windows 10: File type 'Python.File' not found or no open command associated with it

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-10, anaconda, aws-cli

While trying to run aws --version or aws --help or any aws command, I get a strange warning-like error. "File type 'Python.File' not found or no open command associated with it."

```
C:\
λ aws --version
File type 'Python.File' not found or no open command associated with it.
aws-cli/1.16.110 Python/3.6.1 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.100
```

I've tried uninstalling the aws command line application and reinstalling with pip, but no luck.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda, no luck with that either.

Most odd is that I am able to run commands just fine. AWS commands like below work.  They just start with that strange 'Python.File' message :

```
aws s3 sync s3://s3.aws-cli.demo/acme/office C:/Users/Cale/Documents
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue?

Comment: This worked for me: https://superuser.com/questions/429604/passing-arguments-to-a-python-script-file-association-not-found-windows-7-on-i